# Xcode template - use groups instead of folders

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, templates

Im trying to create a `Xcode template` with `folder references` instead of `folders`. I tried a few things found on the web, but nothing seems to work. This is the file structure of my template:
[image]

How can I make it create references instead of folders? Is it even possible?

[image]